# .htaccess to create dynamic subdomain from subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, dynamic, subdomain

I wonder how can create a dynamic subdomain pointing to a folder in root when user search for it. Like apples.domain.com pointing to domain.com/apples (apples folder already created manually). Then if the apples folder do not exist, it retrieves a 404.
Please, help. I'm such a noob with this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

in the htaccess file in the `domain.com`'s document root.

Comment: I customize the code like this
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.tdtw\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 !-d
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.tdtw\.net$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1 -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]` but did not work. URL: tdtw.net, folder created **pepe**

Comment: also need to comment, the server is working slow derp today. It takes seriously minutes to refresh.